# How to pass "javascript" regexes with pymongo?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pymongo

Mongo allows queries like this:

```
{_id: /^84042/}
```

i.e. no `$regex` keyword used.

How to pass the same regexes with `pymongo`?

If I do

```
my_collection.find('_id', '/^84042/')
```

it finds nothing.

**UPDATE**

The point is that I don't know whether I use exact value or regex. Hence, any solution involving `$regex` keyword or regex compiling is not applicable.

It should be the same as in mongo: just value spelling should differ.

Comment: Perhaps, `my_collection.find({"_id": {"$regex": "^84042"}})`?

Comment: You will *need* to know whether you're dealing with a regex or a string value. If you type it yourself you obviously know, because you're either typing a regex or a string literal. But even on the mongo console in Javascript you'd need to know the difference to programmatically produce the correct query. TL;DR: without knowing what it's supposed to be, you cannot treat it correctly.

Comment: The one who type the query NEED to know, but I NEED NOT to know and delegate this to mongo. This is the question.